# How to delete a file on ubuntu with another user?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a file with a user. The file should be created in a manner that another user can delete it (I would be fine with just *any* user being able to delete it).

```
cd /tmp
> test
chmod 666 test
#make file owned by a different user and group
chown tomcat:tomcat test
rm -r test
```

Result:

```
rm: cannot remove 'test': Operation not permitted
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I have to create that file so another user is able to delete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/tmp` directory is a "bit" special.  It has the permissions `1777` which sets the sticky bit.  You'll see that an `ls -l /` shows `tmp` with the permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwt  25 root root      12288 Aug  3 08:20 tmp/
```

That `t` means that it prevents anyone except the owner from removing files.  You'll need to use a different directory.  Additionally, the `-r` doesn't make sense for a file.